# How does "map" interpret its first argument in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have some questions about Perl's "map" function.

Specifically:

- How does

  %hash = map {$_ => 1} @array

  create a hash mapping array's elements to 1? How does block return a list of two elements? I thought block returns its last value. Does => implicitly create a list, as opposed to "," that returns its right argument?
- Why does

  %hash = map ($_ => 1), @array

  not work? I am trying to return a list of two elements here... And how does prepending "+"  before "(" fix it, from the parser's point of view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Question 1: map blocks are run list context, and as such are allowed to return zero, one or more values. `map` returns them all. "`,`" or "`=>`"return their right side in scalar context, but both sides in list context. See [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) for the details.

Question 2: `%hash = map ($_ => 1), @array` is interpreted as `%hash = (map($_,  1), @array)`. In other words, it returns (1, @array).
In `%hash = map +($_ => 1), @array`, the + indicates that the () doesn't refer to an argument list, so it is interpreted as map(+($_ => 1), @array);

The lesson of the day: always use accolades around your map expression, that way you won't be bitten by these kinds of issues.

Comment: Could you add a bit more to your answer to tell me how is block returning multiple values in the first case?

Comment: The context you're not grasping here seems to be context. Perl expressions can have different contexts: void, scalar and list. You're thinking in scalar context, while what's going on here is list context.

Comment: I did not realize , returns both sides in the list context. Thank you!

Comment: I have never seen accolades used to mean braces.

Comment: Another good reason to avoid the "map +($_ => 1), @array" form is that this form contradicts Perl's default behaviour of flattening lists -- in nearly all cases, "func +($_ => 1), @array" is identical to "func($_, 1, @array)", though that's not the case with the map call here.

Comment: The part that confuses me about map is passing an EXPR, and having it not evaluated once, the result being passed into map, but instead being evaluated against each element in the list. :\ i.e., `map foo($_), @bar;` is like `map { foo($_) } @bar;`

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @Leon's correct answers to help you with your second question:

from [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators)

> Unary "+" has no effect whatsoever,
>   even on strings. It is useful
>       syntactically for separating a function name from a parenthesized
>       expression that would otherwise be interpreted as the complete list of
>       function arguments.

You can use deparse to see how perl interprets each:

```
perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e "%h = map ($_ => 1), @a;"
(((%h) = map($_, 1)), @a);
```

where as

```
perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e "%h = map +($_ => 1), @a;"
((%h) = map(($_, 1), @a));
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is a code-block or subroutine.  Code blocks must be surrounded by {}.  They work not-quite like lambdas, but pretty darn close.

Edit: No clue why adding the + after the 1 works.  Perhaps it's compiling to a code block in some weird way?  This doesn't seem to match perldoc.

Answer (score 0):

Map applies the block to each value in the array/list and creates a new list.  => is syntactic sugar to show that the list consists of key/value pairs (IIRC, it would work with ordinary comma as well). When you assign a list of alternatig key/value pairs to a hash variable, a hash table is created.

The other variant does not work because it is not a code block. I don't know about +.

Comment: Your last paragraph is incorrect. A code block is not required as first argument.